# How to Terminate multiple ec2 instances belonging to same security group with ansible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, yaml

I have just started using Ansible for some of my projects. For a test script I've created 57 ec2 instances using ansible. 
All of these instances have same security group in common, It would be a tedious task to terminate them all by instance id's using ansible. Is there any way to terminate these instances using ansible based on some common factor like a security group or a key pair. Can I terminate all instances having same security group or having same key pair without their instance id's using ansible?

Here is the code snippet i used to create these instances.

```
---
  - name: Launching the AWS instance
    hosts: localhost
    tasks:
            - name: Launching the AWS instance
              ec2:
                      key_name: Ansible
                      region: ap-south-1
                      instance_type: t2.micro
                      image: ami-0620d12a9cf777c87
                      group: Akshay_ansible
                      count: 57
                      aws_access_key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                      aws_secret_key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using the [`ec2_instance`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_instance_module.html) module.

```
- ec2_instance:
    state: absent
    filters:
      key-name: Ansible
```

For the list of filters that can be used, refer to the Filter section under Request Parameters [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstances.html).